# All styling (bootstrap, css) goes away when a specific component is rendered and refreshed in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am facing this problem with a component which when renders in the browser, all styling gets removed including the bootstrap css & js. And this is happening when I go to a particular path:

http://localhost:3000/profile/5e85e1ce61fb132564b2e315

If I go to this link through clicking its supposed hyperlink the app, the first time it loads fine. When I refresh it all the styling goes away.
Its not the case with other paths and components, which are rendered fine no matter how many times you refresh them.

I get these errors in the console when it happens:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/mdb.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
popper.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
mdb.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have places those link in my public/index.html file. Here's how it looks:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="./assets/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="./assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

I don't understand why does it try to go to the path: http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/styles.css to fetch these files instead of the path I've given in the index file. Its working fine for the rest of the web application instead of this particular path and component.

Comment: Because it seems that you're doing a server redirection of any path to index.html, this means that for the browser the content root for your site is `/profile/` and therefore all relative assets should load from them `./assets/...` translate to `/profile/assets/`

Comment: But I don't see how. I don't see such redirection from my actions file or even the React code of the component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding this before the link in the head section of the index.html file:

```
<base href="/">
```